# upgrade traditional saddle clamp (not seat tube clamp)?

Tags: saddle, seatpost, folding-bicycle, clamp

I'm currently restoring my folding bike and it has a large diameter (34 mm/1.34 in) seatpost that tapers to the standard 22 mm/0.87 in diameter at the end.

The bike currently uses that traditional saddle clamp that clamps to the seatpost tube.

[image: here's the saddle clamp]

I wanted to upgrade the saddle clamp to the common 1-bolt clamps you see in pre-built seatposts. I eventually found one while searching but it's a bit pricey for my wallet. I liked its design of having a separate bolt for clamping to the tube.

[image: here's the pricey clamp]

Are there any clamps similar to this?

Edit: I also found another design but I'm still checking it out.

[image]

I just really hate having to wrench out nuts in my adjustments, so I wanted a clamp that uses bolts.

Comment: You can find a regular seatpost of ø34 mm which has an integrated saddle clamp for saddles with regular rails, for very nice price, or even nicer if you want to buy used (although the latter might be harder to find as 34 mm is not the most popular diameter)

Comment: Or, you can buy a seatpost with smaller diameter and also a shim to fit larger seat tube diameter: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/614R0baJmrL._SL1024_.jpg

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov I wanted buying a whole integrated seatpost as a last resort and I can't use shims because my folding bike is already using shims even with a 34 mm seatpost tube.

I basically just hate having to wrench out nuts so I wanted a saddle clamp that uses allen/torx bolts.

Comment: Folders have an added problem that the seatpost is often extraordinarily long already.   Lengthening the seatpost may require a one-off custom engineering project.

Comment: @Criggie I'm not trying to lengthen my already-long, 55-inch seatpost tube. I'm looking for a traditional-style saddle clamp that uses allen bolts instead of nuts so that I won't bother with spanners or wrenches anymore.

Comment: @GregoryLeo My point was you could get a modern J bend seatpost with an integrated clamp, and then get it extended by an engineering shop.  This could also do away with your shims.